# How to select a Tr by a value in one of its children

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select the `Tr` which contains in one of its children a hidden field with a specific value.

```
<tr id="tr1">
      <td id="td1">
            <input type="hidden" id="idField" value='theSpecificValue'/>
```

I want to select `tr1` if the hidden field `idField` has a specific value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#idField[value="theSpecificValue"]').closest('tr')
```

Although ids are supposed to be unique, so possibly ignore it and use

```
$('input[value="theSpecificValue"]').closest('tr')
```

Edit:

```
$("tr:has(input:hidden[value=theSpecificValue])")
```

The author for some reason deleted this answer. I liked it better than mine and voted it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.closest('tr')` which will transverse up the DOM, finding the closest `<tr>` element and once found, will stop, unlike `.parents('tr')` which will match all the way to the root (undesired)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the input if it has the value, then find the row from there:

```
$('#idField[value=theSpecificValue]').closest('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input[value='specifiedValue']").parents("#tr1:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are trying to get from tr but you should look up [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent)

so

```
$('#idField).parent();
```

would return

```
<td id="td1">
```

and then you could go up the DOM again with parent().

Comment: I'm using Selectable from JQuery UI on a `Tr` in a table. and I want to select the tr programmatically if a hidden field match a specific value.